# ScrollView cutting off part of view with white bars(SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui

I'm implementing ScrollView in my SwiftUI project but it's cutting off a part of the view:

[image]

How it should look:

[image]

Code:

```
struct ScrollingTest: View {
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
            VStack{
                ForEach(0..<2){ _ in
                    VStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 50, height: 250)
                            .cornerRadius(25)
                            .shadow(radius: 5)
                    }.padding(.top, 15)
                }
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        }
        .offset(x: 20)
    }
}
```

**It doesn't matter which size I set the rectangle it's just always cut off.
**What can I do to fix this? Thanks****

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clipped by scrollview. Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
            VStack{
                ForEach(0..<2){ _ in
                    VStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 50, height: 250)
                            .cornerRadius(25)
                            .shadow(radius: 5)
                    }.padding(.top, 15)
                }
            }.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the way you add the shadow. If you remove the shadow (and change the color of the Rectangle to something other than white, so it won't be white on white invisible) you will see there is no bar. The following looks a bit more like what you want it. Basically your rectangle is on top of a new rectangle so that the shadow is not cut off anymore.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
            VStack{
                ForEach(0..<2){ _ in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 30, height: 250)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        VStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 50, height: 250)
                                .cornerRadius(25)
                                .shadow(radius: 5)
                        }.padding(.top, 15)
                    }

                }
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        }
        .offset(x: 20)
    }
```